# QueryParameter in WireMock

Tags: java, api, mocking, wiremock

I am trying to implement basic query param using WireMock. Here is my code

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/getWithQueryParam?searchFor=WireMock"))
        .withQueryParam("searchFor" ,equalTo("WireMock"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatusMessage("This Page is Authenticated And having query Parameter")));
```

when do or why do we use `withQueryParam("searchFor",equalTo(WireMock)` if we giving params in the `urlEqualTo` method itself.

And is there any way i can read the queryParam and put it in response body ?

Comment: urlPathEqualTo is resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ReponseTemplating should be used to handle to request params. and urlPathEqualTo will used instead if urlEqualTo when we are using withQueryParam

Answer (score 1):

Per the prior answer, this is correct and here's how to do it.  First, ensure you have the 'response-template' transformer set.

```
wm.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/getWithQueryParam"))
  .willReturn(aResponse()
      .withBody("Your value for searchFor is {{request.query.searchFor}}")
      .withTransformers("response-template")));
```